# how to get the\rhead superiorly to the top and \chead down

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

### MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newlength{\tabcont}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.05in}


\title{Assignment 4}


\newcommand{\course}{lipsum}
\newcommand{\coursen}{lipsum}
\newcommand{\semester}{lipsum} 
\newcommand{\TDAG}{lipsum}
\newcommand{\campus}{lipsum}
\newcommand{\dept}{lipsum}



\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\headheight 56.2pt

\chead{\campus \\ \dept \\ \course \\ \coursen }
\lhead{\TDAG}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Submit the following problems which are given in the tutorial 4 as your Assignment 4.
\begin{enumerate}

\item In question 19 ,part (d).
\end{enumerate}
 
\end{document}
```

### The solution I want

After compiling the above document, The `\rhead` and `\chead` are similar in position of height. What I want is to be the `\rhead` to be up and `\chead` to be down/after `\rhead`.

I have revieved a post that included something like `\header[C]` but that did not work. I am using Miktex + texMaker. But **do provide an example if you know how to do with** `\header[C]` :)

## Screenshots

### current one

[image: what I get when I compile the above code]

### solution that I need

[image: I need a code to get this look]

Edit: Some Tex.SE contributor added the images (I had to insert them as links because I was low on reputation), added relevant tags and fixed grammar; thank you.

Comment: Please don't use `\pagestyle{fancyplain}`. It is deprecated and may stop working in the future. Instead use `\fancypagestyle{plain}{. . .}`.

Comment: @Pieter oh thanks. I wonder what  goes inside`{...}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a top aligned `tabular`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=3cm,top=1cm,includehead,headheight=60pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newlength{\tabcont}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.05in}


\title{Assignment 4}

\newcommand{\course}{lipsum}
\newcommand{\coursen}{lipsum}
\newcommand{\semester}{lipsum} 
\newcommand{\TDAG}{lipsum}
\newcommand{\campus}{lipsum}
\newcommand{\dept}{lipsum}



\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\chead{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}\campus \\ \dept \\ \course \\ \coursen \end{tabular}}
\lhead{\TDAG}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
Submit the following problems which are given in the tutorial 4 as your Assignment 4.
\begin{enumerate}

\item In question 19, part (d).
\end{enumerate}
 
\end{document}
```

I have reduced the top margin. You should use `headheight` in the options to `geometry` and also `includehead`. I also added `\cfoot{}` to remove the centered page number.

I'm not sure what's the purpose of a `\parskip` of 1.3mm.

[image]

Comment: You have solved my problem half-way :). i need to get the `\chead` after the `r\head`: not just start from the same line.

Comment: here is my current code:<https://github.com/Gomesz785/proble1/blob/5b55b5853fa58787d104b34deca963def715d47c/problem.tex>

Comment: Updated question: <https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/606551/how-to-make-chead-come-after-printimg-chead-not-starting-in-the-upmost-same-l>

Comment: @Gomesz785 Add a first empty line in the tabular (and update `headheight`)

Comment: working on it. I cannot say what will the results be...

Comment: The purpose of the `\parskip` and other 2 there is to format the para, deleting them gets the 4 in the last line left-outindented. So I have to keep it.