# How to make \chead come after printing \lhead (not starting in the upmost same line)

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

### MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=3cm,top=1cm,includehead,headheight=60pt]{geometry}

\newlength{\tabcont}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.05in}

\title{Assignment 4}

\newcommand{\course}{lipsum}
\newcommand{\coursen}{lipsum}
\newcommand{\semester}{lipsum} 
\newcommand{\TDAG}{lipsum}
\newcommand{\campuslipsum}
\newcommand{\dept}{lipsum}


\fancypagestyle{plain}
\lhead{\TDAG}
\chead{\begin{tabular}[t]{c}\begin{footnotesize}\campus \\ \dept \\ \course \\ \coursen \end{footnotesize}\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum


\end{document}
```

### What I need:

(freehand drawing on a screenshot)

[image: the result that I want]

*By the way an question had been partially answered in [how to get the\rhead superiorly to the top and \chead down](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/606533/how-to-get-the-rhead-superiorly-to-the-top-and-chead-down/606537#606537). This question is an follow up as my need is `\chead` to start after `\lhead`.*

Comment: There is no `\rhead` in your code. Can you be a bit clearer on what you mean by "after"? ...even if you have to draw out what you mean. Also, don't post code to some large document elsewhere. Rather paste *a minimal example* that replicates the issue here.

Comment: @Werner thanks. i  updated the question. Ok. what I mean by after is first print lipsum(`lhead`) and not starting from the line that `lhead` but after the line of `lhead` ; I want to print `chead`. it is like if `lhead` was in the first line; then `lhead` starts in the second line. i think this will give you bit of a explanation here...

Comment: @werner sorry to bother you but i updated the code to A **MWE**. like shrinked it. Can you look? it is at https://github.com/Gomesz785/LatexPlayground/blob/main/problem.tex

Comment: @Werner I believe I have done a good job improving it?

Comment: Has your question been resolved? ...seeing as there's an accepted answer.

Comment: @Werner Yes, I asked how was my edits - As I have been in the site for some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant `lhead` instead of `rhead`.

I guess you mean something like the following:

```
\chead{
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
\campus \\ \dept \\ \course \\ \coursen
  \end{tabular}
}
\lhead{
  \begin{tabular}[b]{p{0.4\textwidth}}
\TDAG \\\hline \\[-2ex]
  \end{tabular}
}
```

[image]

You can fiddle with the `-2ex` to get the proper position.
But please note that you will get a warning about your `\headheight` being too small. This can give some nasty effects. If this is just something on the first page, it may be better to not put it in the header but just a the first part of the document.

Comment: yes. i meant `lhead`. I updated it.

Comment: Oh I will look all the answers, try them out and reply. Thanks for the wonderful answer...